# How change time zone in SQL for a timestamp?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a time variable in a timestamp format (i.e. '25.04.2021  09:00:00')
I found an only way to transform this timestamp in UTC to Helsinki time using this code

```
select FROM_TZ( datetime, 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/Helsinki' AS hel_time
from MYDB
```

However, I got an error. Can you help with the transformation?

Comment: What is the data type of `datetime`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff DATA_TYPE IS `DATE` and JDBC Type is `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: What error did you get? If `datetime` is an Oracle DATE type then you need to do `FROM_TZ(CAST(datetime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')` ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=89e4af0547336097278a7b411ebb12d2)). But where does Java fit in, and where/how are you converting the string (if it is one) to a date or timestamp? If you have a Java variable then you could convert it to the right data type and time zone there, then  pass it to Oracle as the correct date/timestamp value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If datetime is an Oracle DATE type then you cast that to a timestamp:

```
FROM_TZ(CAST(datetime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')
```

giving you:

```
select FROM_TZ(CAST(datetime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC' ) AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/Helsinki' AS hel_time
from MYDB

25-APR-21 12.00.00.000000 EUROPE/HELSINKI
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=89e4af0547336097278a7b411ebb12d2)

it isn't clear where Java fits in, or where you have a 'time' variable.